# Google Analytics not showing desktop visits

Tags: google-analytics, usage-data, desktop

I've had a feeling that my site was getting less visits than usual, and when I looked at Google Analytics in real-time as well as by operating system and mobile devices, I noticed that every single one of my visitors was from a mobile device and on my mobile site (`m.ninjawarrior.info`) and not a single one on the normal site (`ninjawarrior.info`).

I can view my desktop site just fine but my visits don't show up. I double checked that I have the right tracking code, and I do. It's placed in my `<head>` tag towards the bottom with other `<script>` tags.

Why is Google Analytics not showing desktop visits and how can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you added `www.` as the domain to Google Analytics? since just ninjawarrior.info wouldn't be valid due to canonical links you've set. Only reason I ask is you said `not a single one on the normal site (ninjawarrior.info)` without mentioning www.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The biggest reason is that you are using the wrong view.

Make sure that the id in the tracking code is consistent and not -01 for mobile and -02 for desktop.